# AuraEnabled function gets not value from lwc using class type as parameter

Tags: lightning-web-components, class, aura-enabled

i have the following object:

```
public class myType {
   public String name {get; set;}
   public String fields {get; set;}
   public Integer page {get; set;}
   public Integer pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to receive this as a parameter from an aura enabled function:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static object getCount(myType listParams){
    String query = 'SELECT count(ID) FROM ' + listParams.objectName;
    System.debug(listParams);
    System.debug(query);
    return Database.query(query);
}
```

running like this from the lwc component:

```
connectedCallback(){
    var params = {
        objectName: this.sObject,
        fields: this.fields,
        page: this.page,
        pageSize: this.pageSize
    }
    console.log(params)
    getCount({ listParams: params }).then(countResult => {
       console.log(countResult)
    })
}
```

But all the apex get on developer console are null values.
[image: error]

If i change the type to object on the controller i get Map<Any,Any>. What i am doing wrong here?
This does work with SObject types as i have tried it before.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value, you must use @AuraEnabled as well as using the default getter/setter (`{ get; set; }`):

```
public class myType {
   @AuraEnabled public String name {get; set;}
   @AuraEnabled public String fields {get; set;}
   @AuraEnabled public Integer page {get; set;}
   @AuraEnabled public Integer pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

An example is provided in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm).

> ```
> public class SimpleAccount {
>     
>     @AuraEnabled public String Id { get; set; }
>     @AuraEnabled public String Name { get; set; }
>     public String Phone { get; set; }
>     
>     // Trivial constructor, for server-side Apex -> client-side JavaScript
>     public SimpleAccount(String id, String name, String phone) {
>         this.Id = id;
>         this.Name = name;
>         this.Phone = phone;
>     }
>     
>     // Default, no-arg constructor, for client-side -> server-side
>     public SimpleAccount() {}
>     
> }
> ```
>
> When returned from a remote Apex controller action, the Id and Name properties are defined on the client-side. However, because it doesn’t have the @AuraEnabled annotation, the Phone property isn’t serialized on the server side, and isn’t returned as part of the result data.